# i have a multi line string from this i need sun string ...?Here is the input string and required output string i have placed

Tags: python

Input String:-

```
r="""Jun 5 13:09:36.132: %ASESDK-5-NOTICE: dcmd[6670] 879 libloadindexmapmanager.ResilienceStatusEventHandler: uid=[1804108988984000615]userplaneFullyResilient:        User plane resilience alarm cleared in 899 seconds, affected users 0 (1)...
   Jun 5 13:09:36.132: %ASESDK-5-NOTICE: dcmd[6670] 879 libloadindexmapmanager.ResilienceStatusEventHandler: .333252 (2)"""
```

Required Output:-

```
r="""Jun 5 13:09:36.132: %ASESDK-5-NOTICE: dcmd[6670] 879 libloadindexmapmanager.ResilienceStatusEventHandler: uid=[1804108988984000615]userplaneFullyResilient:        User plane resilience alarm cleared in 899 seconds, affected users 0.333252 """
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
import re

regex = r"(.*) \(1\)(.*): (.*) "

new_string = ""

test_str = "Jun 5 13:09:36.132: %ASESDK-5-NOTICE: dcmd[6670] 879 libloadindexmapmanager.ResilienceStatusEventHandler: uid=[1804108988984000615]userplaneFullyResilient: User plane resilience alarm cleared in 899 seconds, affected users 0 (1)... Jun 5 13:09:36.132: %ASESDK-5-NOTICE: dcmd[6670] 879 libloadindexmapmanager.ResilienceStatusEventHandler: .333252 (2)"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    new_string = (match.group(1) + match.group(3))

print (new_string)
```

Output is:

```
Jun 5 13:09:36.132: %ASESDK-5-NOTICE: dcmd[6670] 879 libloadindexmapmanager.ResilienceStatusEventHandler: uid=[1804108988984000615]userplaneFullyResilient: User plane resilience alarm cleared in 899 seconds, affected users 0.333252
```